# No me añade dato al Array en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo este código

```
  var tablasPre = [];
  var tab = ['t13','t010'];

  for(var i = 0; i<tab.length; i++){
     recuperarTabla(tab[i]);
  }

  function recuperarTabla(nomTab){
   var url = "/json/"+nomTab+".json";
   HttpSrv.get(url).then(function(resultado){
       tablasPre[nomTab] = resultado;
       console.log('prueba  '+Object.keys(tablasPre).length)
   });
  }

  console.log('prueba 1 '+Object.keys(tablasPre).length)
```

una vez que que compruebo la longitud de `tablasPre` me indica que es 0, lo suyo seria que fuera así:
`tablasPre['t13']`
`tablasPre['t10']`.

La prueba me muestra 2 pero prueba 1 me muestra 0

Sabrías porque no me lo añade?
Muchas gracias

Comment: no es un array, es un objeto! cuando haces `tablasPre[nomTab]` estas agregando una propiedad a tu objeto

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos problemas:

En cuanto a la estructura de datos: cuando las claves de un array son strings, pasa a ser un array asociativo, y dicho *array* no tiene una propiedad `length`, se comporta como un objeto literal. Ejemplo:

```js
var array = [];

array['str'] = "cero";
array['str1'] = "uno";
array['str2'] = "dos";

console.log(array);
console.log(array.str1);//<-- funciona como un objeto literal
console.log(array.length); //<-- no tiene propiedad lenght 
console.log(Object.keys(array).length) //<-- funciona como un objeto literal
```

El otro problema es que `.get` es una función asíncrona por lo que el segundo `console` se ejecuta antes que el primero. El segundo `console` solo va a tener los datos si está dentro de una función `async`, en un `then()` o `resolve()`, pero como tienes un loop de llamadas asíncronas, lo mejor sería usar `Promise.all()`, ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/mfdabj6n/

Comment: Vale así si que me muestra en la function el  número que tiene pero si añado después de la function el mismo console me muestra cero, lo modifico a como lo tengo ahora, es como si al salir ya no se guardará los valores...

Comment: Eso es porque el .get es asíncrono, el segundo console se ejecuta antes que el primero

Comment: como podría corregir esto? con post?